# API urls: Implicit vs Explicit tenant ids

Tags: api, http, caching, multi-tenant

Within a multi tenant app, I have two choices to expose my resources:

```
  api.myapp.com/customer/{id}
  api.mayap.com/{tenant}/customer/{id}
```

I am wondering about the pros and cons of exposing the tenant name. In the first case the tenant name is given as a header field, and in the second directly within the URL.

On one hand I do want to have the cleanest and simplest possible URL structure. Since all resource IDs will be UUIDs, having the tenant namespace seems redundant.

On the other I am not sure if having the tenant name exposed in the URLs will make caching easier or any other factor I have not yet considered (monitoring, integration with third party services, etc)

**Which are the downsides of removing the tenant namespace from an API?**

**Which are the factors I should consider while making this choice?**

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest the use of the 
`api.myapp.com/customer/{id}` model for the following reasons

1. In case you pass the tenant id in the URL, there may be a security risk if the tenant id is not validated properly at the Api Layer, like if the logged in use has access to that tenant / entity / record etc
2. URL's are not clean [as you rightly said]
3. In case your provide the entity access to a different tenant, the URL model would lead to confusions on who owns the data and who gets to view the data alone.

Please share your take on the above considerations.